# Sum of three cross products is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

Let $u,v,w\in \mathbb R^3$. Prove $u \times( v \times w)+v \times( w \times u)+w \times( u \times v) =0$

I guess things would work out if I just expanded as a ton of products. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you might use that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a property which should make this question easier:

$$a \times (b \times c) = b(a \cdot c) - c(a \cdot b)$$

You will notice that all the terms cancel out, leading to the answer of $0$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x,y,z) = x \times (y \times z) + y \times (z \times x) + z \times (x \times y)$  is linear in each of $x$, $y$, $z$, 
so it suffices to prove for the cases where each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ is one of the three standard unit vectors $i$, $j$, $k$.
Now $f(x,y,z)$  is multiplied by $-1$ if you interchange any two of $x$, $y$ and $z$: in particular if two are equal it must be $0$.  So only one case needs to be computed: 
$$ f(i,j,k) = i \times (j \times k) + j \times (k \times i) + k \times (i \times j)$$
where each of the terms is $0$